# How to test classes with private constructors

Tags: java, flutter, unit-testing, dart, domain-driven-design

### TLDR Version

How should I test an object with a private constructor being created in a factory class?

### Full Version:

I'm trying to learn test-driven development, and my password value objects have to be validated on creation. I also want to use the validation in the UI's presenter/controller code to validate the password TextFields. These are the classes I'm using.

### Password class

```dart
import '../services/password_specification.dart';
import '../../../domain_base/value_object.dart';

part 'password_factory.dart';

class Password extends ValueObject<Password>{
  const Password._(this.value);

  @override
  int getHashCode() {
    return value.hashCode;
  }

  @override
  bool sameAs(Password other) {
    return value == other.value;
  }


  
  final String value;
}
```

### Password Factory class

```
part of 'password.dart';

class PasswordFactory {
  const PasswordFactory(this._specification);
  
  Password create(String value) {
    if(!_specification.isValid(value))
      throw Error();

    return new Password._(value);
  }  

  final PasswordSpecification _specification;
}
```

### Password Specification class

```dart
class PasswordSpecification {
  const PasswordSpecification();

  bool isValid(String password) {
    if(password.length < 6)
      return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

Since the password specification is in a separate class, I'll have to add that as a dependency to my Password class. But I don't want to have to have an instance of password specification injected into my Password Value object class.

So instead I created a PasswordFactory class to construct my Password class. The factory class gets a PasswordSpecification object injected to it and then in the create function it uses that to validate the password and then return a password if the password matches the specification, else it throws an error. This ensures Password object cant be created if it fails validation.

I also made my Password class' constructor private to library so that invalid Password object can't be created using that constructor. Because of this change, my factory also has part of the Password class' library to use the Password class' private constructor. (I'm having second thoughts on using part and part of too, so any advice here too would be nice).

Now the problem comes when I try to test the Password class. How will I be able to test the password class if its constructor is private :). If I should mock the PasswordFactory class to return a Password object how can I do that?

Any advice on what to do would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Although I think is correct sometimes is not your case. Simply define many PasswordSpecs as you need, let anybody instantiate it and test normally and let your factory resolve the dependency. Or, why I should not instantiate a PasswordSpecs?

Comment: Instantiating PasswordSpecs multiple times is fine and I have the specs as a seperate class for the same reason(to validate UI TextFields), my problem is with wanting Password to be valid all the time which led to the private constructor which in turn lead to the testing problem.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I test an object with a private constructor being created in a factory class?

Test it via the Factory.  After all, that is how clients of the Password class are going to use it.

Remember: unit tests are not a *goal*.  They are a pattern that arises frequently in service of a goal.  The goal is code without mistakes; in cases where you can better deliver that goal using a different testing technique, then you should do that.

---

Note that if you really wanted to "unit test" Password.class, you could do that.  You would prepare a classpath where all of the other components are known good (the Java native libraries, third party code you trust, your own code that has passed its tests), then copy your Password.class subject into that harness, and run your tests.

So the fact that your unit tests includes a lot of fixed dependencies doesn't matter: the thing you are measuring is the class file you have prepared for Password.

The cost / benefit ratio for doing it this way is trash, of course, unless your system is already designed to allow you to deploy Password.class independently of everything else.

Testing where the units are "deployment scale" (package/jar/worktree) is a lot more common when developers are running the tests.

Comment: "Remember: unit tests are not a goal" - well put, I wish more people understood that

Comment: I was doing it by using the factory to construct it and was testing that object, but wanted to know if there was another way. Thanks for setting me straight :) . Regarding the other problem, using part of is not recommended in the dart docs. They instead recommend 'mini libraries'. So is me using 'part of' to make the factory part of the same library as the password class to use the private constructor fine and can I consider that as a 'mini library', or if its kinda ugly, is there another way?